# Question captcha bypassed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, captcha

I just answered a question and on clicking "Post Your Answer", nothing happened. I copied my answer, reloaded the page and tried to submit it again; then it asked me to enter a captcha "Verify that you are human". I dismissed this message by hitting the "X" in the top right corner, hit "Post your Answer" again and the answer got posted without me entering captcha code.

Is this a bug?

Not sure whether I can reproduce because it is the first time in over a year it asking me for a captcha ....

Comment: ... you avoided to answer the question. *Are* you human?

Comment: It was asking you to solve a captcha because you submitted your answer so quickly after you started writing it the second time.

Comment: @Jongware Please.. I am cyborg.. is it ok to answer :-( Thx Anonymous, that sounds like the answer. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, I was just pointing out why. If the bug happened, then I see no reason to delete the question.

Comment: Specially because spam bots could use that bug, if it is reproducible.

Comment: AFAIK If you try to submit another answer within 60 seconds you get tested for being a human. Since you closed the box and 60 passed already you were able to just submit the answer again.

Comment: I dunno I posted answers seconds after the question before but I used to always be asked a captcha when not doing that, in fact that was the one time I was safe, but have not been asked for about 2 years now, I swear it was rep linked.

Comment: @Sammaye: It is rep linked.  High rep users still can get hit with captchas, but they are much less common.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like the first time you attempted to post, the submission was successful, and the acknowledgement got lost (well, in a TCP connection, delayed for an exorbitant number of retries, which is the same from the user's perspective).

The second time, you failed a check on the server for multiple answers submitted within a short space of time, which is one of the triggers for the CAPTCHA.

You failed the CAPTCHA, your duplicate post was cancelled, and after returning to the question you saw your answer for the first time, concluding that the CAPTCHA was ineffective somehow, while in fact it was the original attempt succeeded, not the CAPTCHA-protected one.

It's human nature to ascribe effects to the most proximate action, but sometimes that's a bad assumption.

Comment: "and the acknowledgement got lost" :O a bit far fetched assumption, at least until we know whether OP has some connection problems sometimes.

Comment: I usually don't have connection problems. But the explanation is still the most reasonable.

Comment: I now come to think it's browser cache related.

Comment: Captcha cannot be circumvented, so I must assume this to be the most likely scenario as well.